# How to get iPhone Maps app blue dot with light blue field for current location?

Tags: swift, annotations, mapkit

I think the title is quite self explanatory. Currently when I add a default annotation for current location:

```
let currentAnnot = MKPointAnnotation()
currentAnnot.coordinate = loc.coordinate
mainMap.addAnnotation(currentAnnot)
```

It is giving me a red pin. I want the same blue dot with light blue field which the Apple iPhone Maps app is using by default. Is there a special name for that and how can I add it?

Comment: I think you are looking for https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPinAnnotationView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKPinAnnotationView/pinColor but it is deprecated maybe this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32815402/2303865

Comment: Do you mean `MKUserLocation`? You do not create instances of this class directly. If you want to add blue dot on Map, you need to use blue dot image file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you're adding an annotation (pin) rather than the user location.

Enable it by using the following

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = true
```

[Also check out a tutorial which may help](https://www.veasoftware.com/tutorials/2015/7/25/map-view-current-location-in-swift-xcode-7-ios-9-tutorial)

Comment: Thank you. Even though this code kept throwing "MKMapView does have a member showUserLocation", I found there was actually a checkbox to that effect in IB!